# How to use Java Card crypto sample?

Tags: java, servlets, encryption, javacard

I'm trying to make run [example from IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-satsa2/tmp0002.html#IDAIUV3C). 
I wrote this method:

```
public static byte[] cipher(byte[] inputData) {
    Cipher cipher
        = Cipher.getInstance(
                Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, true);

    DESKey desKey = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
                             KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
                             KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES,
                             false);

    byte[] keyBytes = {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04};
    desKey.setKey(keyBytes, (short) 0);

    cipher.init(desKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
    byte[] outputData = new byte[8];

    cipher.doFinal(inputData, (short) 0, (short) inputData.length, outputData, (short) 0);
    return outputData;
}
```

And call this method `cipher("test".getBytes());`. When I call this servlet server gives me Internal server error and `javacard.security.CryptoException`.

I tried `ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1`, `ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2` (and others) and got the same exception.

How to make run simple example of cipher on Java Card Connected?

**UPDATE**

As @vojta said, key must be 8 bytes long. So it must be something like this:

```
byte[] keyBytes = {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04};
```

I don't know why, but it works only if replace

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, true);
```

with

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2, false);
```

I could not find anything about it in documentation.

Comment: Just a few comments: do not create new byte arrays in methods -> you will run out of memory very soon. `outputData` array should be longer, right? Otherwise it can hold just one block of data.

Comment: Thank you. It's just a sample, but I'll take into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

These lines seem to be wrong:

```
byte[] keyBytes = {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04};
desKey.setKey(keyBytes, (short) 0);
```

DES key should be longer than 4 bytes, right? Standard DES key is 8 bytes long (with strength of 56 bits).

Comment: I changed it to        
    byte[] keyBytes 
                    = {(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,
                       (byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04};
But got the same exception.

Comment: @user980828 what is the result of getReason called on your exception instance?

Comment: Result of getReason() is 3.

Comment: @user980828 it means "no such algorithm". Does your card support classic DES?

Comment: actually I use default JC platform. Without card.

Comment: @user980828 could you please try replacing `Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, true);` with `Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);`? I think default platform does not support external access...

Comment: Same result of getReason() --- 3.

Comment: @user980828 May I ask you to retry with `keyBytes = {(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF};` also?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vojta's answer, the input data should be block aligned.

Your input data `"test".getBytes()` have length 4 which is not valid for `Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD` (but valid for `Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2`).

Strange is that this should cause `CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE` reason (which is 5 opposed to 3 you are getting)...